# Get A Users Over All Retweet and Mention Counts using Twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

We are working on some analytics using the amount a user is retweeted or mentioned... I can't seem to find a way to get these numbers using the apis does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name={screen_name}&count={count}

it's important to include the line `include_entities=true` to the request. This will give you an expanded response including re-tweet and mention counts.

[Get Status / User Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

[Twitter API Console](https://dev.twitter.com/console)

**Update:**

to get tweets from the last 90 days, there is a Node.js library you can use called Snapbird

https://github.com/remy/snapbird

.. and here is another resource covering the same topic.

http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-search/10-ways-and-20-features-for-searching-old-tweets/

Comment: Thanks egfx,  does this only show's how the last {count} tweets were retweeted?  We really would like to know a count of how many of their tweets (maybe in the last 90 days) were retweeted.

Comment: You can use the `since` and `until` operator. `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name={screen_name}&since:2011-05-16&until:2011-08-16`

Comment: ..but keep in mind that even given the operator it probably won't return you tweets from a 90 day span because it's above the limit. See my answer update for a way around this.